# How to solve android studio first run issue?

Tags: android, linux

I installed android studio on my reinstalled 20.10 groovy gorilla. When I run it, I find this error:
[image: This error]

And then I get this error if i click cancel:
[image]

Please help me solve this error.

Comment: Try downloading the android SDK again. That might help. Because from the picture, I think the error is with the SDK.

Comment: I did that a 100 times. But still it's like this

Comment: How to download the SDK seperately?

Comment: I have reinstalled

Comment: I told you. The problem is with the SDK.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work properly

Comment: Yeah. I get it. The problem is with the SDK, But still I cant solve it.

Comment: I just changed the location of the sdk from usr/lib/android-sdk to home directory

Comment: Exactly that is the location where you keep your sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the program from the terminal by entering the directory where the program is stored and typing `open -a programNameHere`. If that doesn't work, delete and reinstall the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

It is more of a Linux permission related. You might have extracted android studio into `/opt` as they have mentioned in documentation. I can suggest few solutions.

1. Extract android studio in home directory of user. Make sure not to use `sudo` or `root` to extract tar. Since you are extracting in user home directory, you don't have to use root.

**OR**

2. Install (extract) **Android Studio** in `/opt` with proper permissions.

   1. Create a new directory in `/opt/android`, using `sudo mkdir /opt/android`.
   2. Change ownership of `/opt/android` directory to the current user, using `sudo chown -R <USERNAME> /opt/android`. Replace **<USERNAME>** with the current username.
   3. Extract android studio tar file in `/opt/android` directory. **Don't** use `sudo` or `root` extract files.

> PS: Above mentioned solution no. 2 is dirty solution. `/opt` directory is used for multi user application. To allow multiple user, we have to create system account and add current user to newly created account's group. If you are not looking for `multiuser` solution then go with solution **1**